# JqGrid's colModel from JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, grails, jqgrid

Hi All I have using grails jqGrid plugin.

I want to pass colModel by AJAX response but i can't do this please suggest. Here is my code which i am using.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                var col_names = [];
                var col_model = [];    
                $.ajax({
              url: 'myURL',
              success: function(data) {
                col_names =  "'First Name', 'Last Name', 'E-mail', 'Country','id'";
                col_model =  "{name:'firstName', editable: true},{name:'lastName', editable: true},{name:'email', editable: true},{name:'country', editable: true},{name:'id', hidden: true}"
             }
     });
                             <jqgrid:grid
                              id="contact"
                              url="'${createLink(action: 'listJSON')}'"
                              async =true
                              editurl="'${createLink(action: 'editJSON')}'"
                              colNames = col_names 
                              colModel= col_model
                              sortname="'lastName'"
                              caption="'Contact List'"
                              height="300"
                              autowidth="true"
                              scrollOffset="0"
                              viewrecords="true"
                              showPager="true"
                              datatype="'json'">
                               <jqgrid:navigation id="contact" add="true" edit="true" 
                                    del="true" search="true" refresh="true" />
                              <jqgrid:resize id="contact" resizeOffset="-2" />
                       </jqgrid:grid>
             });
```

Comment: Probably the `data` object returned from the server could have `colName` and `colModel` properties which will be array of items (!!! not strings)? Like `{colName: ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'E-mail', 'Country','id'], colModel: [{name:'firstName', editable: true},{name:'lastName', editable: true},{name:'email', editable: true},{name:'country', editable: true},{name:'id', hidden: true}]}`. The exact object on the server depends on the language which you use on the server side.

Comment: thanks for reply but the above code had static  colName ,colModel but it still not working.

Comment: I mean that such response **generate your server code which you call in `url: 'myURL'`**. So the response should be object with wto properties: `colName` and `colModel`. The object need be returned JSON encoded. The value of `colName` property should be array of strings and so on. I just included in my last response the example of **data** which one should see in `success` callback function.

Comment: in the above code i have just pass the hard code value of colName and colModel but its not mapped properly .